# Authorization with RolesAllowedDynamicFeature and Jersey

Tags: java, authentication, jersey, authorization, jax-rs

I'm trying to authenticate users with a JAX-RS filter what seems to work so far. This is the filter where I'm setting a new SecurityContext:

```
@Provider
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

    requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
      @Override
      public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return new Principal() {
          @Override
          public String getName() {
            return "Joe";
          }
        };
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isUserInRole(String string) {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isSecure() {
        return requestContext.getSecurityContext().isSecure();
      }

      @Override
      public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return requestContext.getSecurityContext().getAuthenticationScheme();
      }
    });

    if (!isAuthenticated(requestContext)) {
      requestContext.abortWith(
              Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
              .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Example\"")
              .entity("Login required.").build());
    }
  }

  private boolean isAuthenticated(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    return requestContext.getHeaderString("authorization") != null; // simplified
  }
}
```

The resource method looks like this:

```
  @GET
  // @RolesAllowed("user")
  public Viewable get(@Context SecurityContext context) {
    System.out.println(context.getUserPrincipal().getName());
    System.out.println(context.isUserInRole("user"));
    return new Viewable("index");
  }
```

The RolesAllowedDynamicFeature is registered like this:

```
.register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class)
```

I can see the expected outputs on the console. But if I uncomment `@RolesAllowed("user")`, I get a `Forbidden` error and the `isUserInRole` method of my SecurityContext is never called. Following the [API doc](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.html) RolesAllowedDynamicFeature should call this method.

How can I use RolesAllowedDynamicFeature?

Answer (score 19):

You need to define a priority for your authentication filter, otherwise the `RolesAllowedRequestFilter` in `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` will be executed before your `AuthenticationFilter`. If you look at the source code, the `RolesAllowedRequestFilter` has the annotation `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)`, so if you assign `@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)` to your authentication filter it will be executed before the `RolesAllowedRequestFilter`. Like this:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
```

You might also need to actually register the `AuthenticationFilter` using `register(AuthenticationFilter.class)`, depending on if your server scans for annotations or not.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. I was setting the priority by using the register(AuthenticationFilter.class, Priorities.AUTHENTICATION) but apparently somehow that was totally ignored. Using the annotation fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because of

```
 @Override
  public boolean isUserInRole(String string) {
    return false;
  }
```

Which states, that the user has not the required role @RolesAllowed("user") to even enter the execution of the annotated method.

You should implement a more sophisticated isUserInRole Method that checks, wheter a User has a specific Role or not :)

regards