# Securing with roles annotations not working (Jersey)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm new here even though I've found many answers to my problems in here before.

Now I'm looking for help with this: I have this little example resource on my little REST API:

```
@Path("/greeting")
@PermitAll
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("all")
    public String sayHelloToAll() {
        return "Hello, everybody!";
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @RolesAllowed("admin")
    @Path("admin")
    public String sayHelloToAdmin() {
        return "Hello, admin!";
    }
}
```

In order to filter roles, I have this implementation of SecurityContext:

```
public class Authorizer implements SecurityContext {

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this implementation of ContainerRequestFilter:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer());
    }
}
```

This is my application class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application() {
        super(HelloResource.class);
        register(AuthorizationFilter.class);
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);        
    }
}
```

With all this, when I request the URI greeting/all, everything is ok, the string "Hello, everybody!" is shown. But when I request the URI greeting/admin, which should be called when an user in admin role requests it, is never invoked, even when my isUserInRole method always returns true. In fact, my filter method is always called, but my isUserInRole method is never called.

I have followed many advices:

[SecurityContext doesn't work with @RolesAllowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536321/securitycontext-doesnt-work-with-rolesallowed)

[Authorization with RolesAllowedDynamicFeature and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068528/authorization-with-rolesalloweddynamicfeature-and-jersey)

[How to access Jersey resource secured by @RolesAllowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817210/how-to-access-jersey-resource-secured-by-rolesallowed/32817513#32817513)

[Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey)

But it doesn't seem to work with anything.

Can anyone please help me? I don't know is there is something I am missing

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT: When I request the URI greeting/admin I get 403 Forbiden by the way (I forgot to say that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the [`RoleAllowedRequestFilter`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.22.1/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java#L120). When a user is authenticated, it is expected that there be an associated `Principal`. The filter checks it [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.22.1/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java#L138)

```
if (rolesAllowed.length > 0 && !isAuthenticated(requestContext)) {
    throw new ForbiddenException(LocalizationMessages.USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED());
}
...
private static boolean isAuthenticated(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    return requestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal() != null;
}
```

So you need to return a `Principal` in the `getUserPrincipal` of the `SecurityContext`

```
@Override
public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
    return new Principal() {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Some Name";
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I had not thought about it